# How to write and consume oracle procedure in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

As I am new in Oracle and don't have much experience how to create & consume oracle procedure. Can someone please help me to fix my code below.

**Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sprocGetTableColumns (
   p_table_name in user_tab_columns.table_name%type,
   po_userdisp_cur  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN po_userdisp_cur 
     FOR SELECT u.Column_Name,
                u.Data_Type,
                u.Nullable 
                FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS u
                WHERE u.table_name = p_table_name  order by column_id
 
 END sprocGetTableColumns;
```

**C# Code**

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(templateSettingModel.ConnectionString))
                {

                    OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
                    objCmd.Connection = conn;
                    objCmd.CommandText = "sprocGetTableColumns";
                    objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    objCmd.Parameters.Add("@tableName", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = 20;
                    objCmd.Parameters.Add("P_COLUMN_NAMES", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    await conn.OpenAsync();
                    var dataReader = await objCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        var item = new TemplateFieldMappingModel
                        {
                            ColumnName = CommonHelper.To<string>(dataReader["COLUMN_NAME"]),
                            DataType = CommonHelper.To<string>(dataReader["DATA_TYPE"]),
                            IsNullable = CommonHelper.To<bool>(dataReader["IS_NULLABLE"])
                        };

                        // set the field name to be the same as the column name
                        item.FieldName = item.ColumnName;

                        if (!item.IsNullable)
                            item.IsRequired = true;

                        models.Add(item);
                    }
                    await dataReader.CloseAsync();
```

Comment: You haven't said what problem you have or what needs to be fixed? You should probably tag for c# too - which is not my area. A few things looks potentially problematic though: `CommandText` *might* need to be uppercase; should `@tableName` be `P_TABLE_NAME`; should the value for that be an actual table name (also matching case from data dictionary, uppercase by default) not `20`?; should `P_COLUMN_NAMES` be `PO_USERDISP_CUR`; and in the data read should `IS_NULLABLE` just be `NULLABLE`? Mostly speculating...

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for reply. The problematic area is primarily the store procedure. as I don't know how to fix the issues of this store proc and secondly if some one helps me in correcting the above c# code.

Comment: Fix what issues? You still haven't said what's wrong. You're missing a semicolon at the end of the query - after `order by column_id` - but what else is it telling you? Please edit the question to include the full error(s) you get, from Oracle and C#. You can query `user_errors` if you can't see the procedure errors already.

Comment: @AlexPoole : Below are the list of issues I was facing and after putting semi colon it compiles successfully.  

1)  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2)  PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
3)  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the .

Will it call directly from code like MSSQL store proc or need to do something before calling it?

Comment: Well, it's missing a semicolon as I already said, and you need a slash on a line on its own to complete the PL/SQL block. Both of which are typos really. I don't know what you mean about calling it, if you get errors from C# then **add them to the question**.